# Best technology for Java based simple CRUD web site

Tags: java, web-applications, crud

I want to create a CRUD (create, retrieve, update, delete) web site using the simplest Java tools.  This site will allow users to manage four tables, two of which are reference tables used to build menus and two of which will undergo CRUD activity.

I'm leaning toward Stripes but I would like to hear the opinions of experience developers. The three key requirement are simple, simple, simple! I think Struts and Spring MVC are more complicated than I need.

-=beeky

Answer (score 16):

[grails](http://grails.org/) because your workflow will become:

1. Define classes for your Domain objects
2. run grails generate-all

And you will have a very simple CRUD application that *also* can be extended to "real application status" without throwing out everything and starting again. CRUD in grails takes no more than 5 minutes. For serious. Check out [Scott Davis' intro tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails01158/).

Comment: Although I upvoted since I agree, outlining the reasons might be helpful.

Comment: Grails is perfect, because it has CRUD Support built in. You can create Controllers and Domains with very simple code generation tools, and validaton is also included.
One thing to say: Things get complicated once you move away from simple crud and relational stuff, but CRUD itself is in there out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

The simpliest application would be a simple servlet handling a java-based sql engine (e.g. Derby (jabaDB)  or HSQLDB)

You could even think of a CGI written in Java.

Comment: +1 for being the only remotely sensible answer (that actually read the question) so far.

Answer (score 2):

I would use Grails since it fits perfectly to your requirements. I've never created simple CRUD websites faster. Stripes programming model is more like a tuned Struts - somewhat awkward.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use an administration interface, which will provide CRUD capabilities, validation, filtering data, security and which will have a simple and clean UI (like admin panel in Django or ActiveAdmin/Ruby).

The only **Java** solution I know is [LightAdmin](http://lightadmin.org). It's pluggable open-source Java library for JPA-backed applications, which provides an **administration interface** for your JPA data model. It has a build-in DSL for UI customization and is based on Spring tech stack.

The good thing about **LightAdmin** is that you don't need to maintain all the supporting code in your codebase. All is bundled in the library, including UI.

Answer (score 1):

rails on jruby or Grails. Yes, it's a different language, but they are not hard to learn and is worth it.

Comment: I don't get you Ruby people giving Ruby answers to Java questions.  Sigh.  Even when I ignore Ruby on SO, I still get force-fed Ruby.  :-)  <- See the smiley, it's sarcasm.  Don't bite my head off.

Answer (score 1):

I propose GWT (google web toolkit), although I never played with Grails.

With GWT, your client gui is all written in java. There is a compiler that is used to create a javascript version of the application. So it's really easy to create simple GUI that reflects your object. When the user presses "Save", the object is received on the server side ready to be saved. Then, just use hibernate/JPA to save the object to the database.

We use to have a simple internal tool like that to manager user rights. The administrator just had to check/uncheck a checkbox. An AJAX call would send the updated object to the server, which just call save() on the hibernate layer.

Answer (score 1):

I won't recommend using a framework in your case. Simple jsp/servlet with jdbc should work.

But,If you do decide on using a framework, from my experience of having used Stripes,Struts1 and JSF(MyFaces) ,recommend Stripes without hesitation.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Java solution, based on Tapestry, check out [Tynamo](http://tynamo.org). Fits the bill,  it's simple but extensible, no extra fluff. Agree with the previous comment, H2 is an amazing little database and it's what Tynamo uses by default as well

Answer (score 0):

Try [tox](http://tox.sourceforge.net/) with [Oracle XE](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html).  Both are free.  Tox is GPLv2.  Its a MVC architecture using XSLT, JavaScript, and PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple Java Web stack I've been using lately:

- **Database** [H2](http://ttp://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)
- **RESTful routing** [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/)

Restlets can be run in any servlet container. Although they haven't worked well in Simple or Winstone, they have worked well for me in Jetty.

Optionally, [H2 could be combined with Active Objects](http://www.manskes.de/index.php/2008/10/30/the-simplest-activeobjects-database-provider-for-the-h2-database/) to give very lightweight persistence, but I haven't tried this myself.

If your data  volume is small and you really want simple, why not ditch the rdbms altogether and use [Prevayler](http://prevayler.codehaus.org/), giving a complete stack consisting of just Restlet, and Prevayler?

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider Spring Roo, which is basically the pure-Java equivalent of Grails.